# Replace word with random words on click Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have inserted a short story and want to change certain words on click to a random word. Here is what I have so far just trying to get the word 'lion' to be replaced with nothing. I am getting no change at all. Any ideas?

```js
let C = document.getElementsByClassName("lion");
//console.log(CL);
let L = C.length;
//console.log(LL);
for (var i = 0; i < L; i++)
  C[i].addEventListener("click", changeLion);

function changeLion() {
  console.log("clicked");
  let CC = document.getElementsByClassName("lion");
  console.log(CC);
  for (var i = 0; i < CC.length; i++)
    C[i].style.color = "";
}
```

```html
<h1>THE <span class="lion">LION</span> AND THE <span class="mouse">MOUSE</span></h1>
<p style="font-size: 1.5em;">
  A <span class="lion">Lion</span> asleep in his lair was waked up by a <span class="mouse">Mouse</span> running over his face. Losing his temper he seized it with his paw and was about to kill it. The <span class="mouse">Mouse</span>, terrified, piteously
  entreated him to spare its life. "Please let me go," it cried, "and one day I will repay you for your <span class="kindness">kindness</span>." The idea of so insignificant a creature ever being able to do anything for him amused the <span class="lion">Lion</span>  so much that he <span class="laugh">laughed</span> aloud, and good-humouredly let it go. But the <span class="mouse">Mouse</span>'s chance came, after all. One day the <span class="lion">Lion</span> got entangled in a net which had been spread for game
  by some hunters, and the <span class="mouse">Mouse</span> heard and recognised his roars of <span class="anger">anger</span> and ran to the spot. Without more ado it set to work to gnaw the ropes with its teeth, and succeeded before long in setting
  the <span class="lion">Lion</span> free. "There!" said the <span class="mouse">Mouse</span>, "you <span class="laugh">laughed</span> at me when I promised I would repay you: but now you see, even a <span class="mouse">Mouse</span> can help a <span class="lion">Lion</span>."
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>*Written by Aesop
</p>
```

Comment: you're removing any `color` styling, but don't have any styling in the first place, which is why you can't "see" anything happening. Were the "lion" spans supposed to have a color in the first place?

Comment: apologies. that was supposed to read C[i].textContent = ""; that is now working but not sure how to generate/output the random word to replace lion

Comment: What do u mean by random `xnwu` is a random word or do u mean a random word from predefined list like `[bear, goat, ...]`

Comment: @Rana predefined list that I will be adding myself

Comment: another thing I forgot to note. I want the lion (or the word it changes to) to change each time it is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array which contains a predefined list of names and than using a [random number generator](https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_random.asp) [`Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;`: where `min` value is `0` and `max` value is `3`] .

You can than take random values from the array.

```js
let C = document.getElementsByClassName("lion");
//console.log(CL);
let L = C.length;
//console.log(LL);
for (var i = 0; i < L; i++) {
  C[i].addEventListener("click", changeLion);
}


arrayNames = ['bear', 'goat', 'sheep', 'wolf']

function changeLion() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  console.log(randomNumber)
  let CC = document.getElementsByClassName("lion");
  for (var i = 0; i < CC.length; i++) {
    C[i].style.color = "red";
    C[i].innerHTML = arrayNames[randomNumber];
  }
}
```

```css
.lion {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>THE <span class="lion">LION</span> AND THE <span class="mouse">MOUSE</span></h1>
<p style="font-size: 1.5em;">
  A <span class="lion">Lion</span> asleep in his lair was waked up by a <span class="mouse">Mouse</span> running over his face. Losing his temper he seized it with his paw and was about to kill it. The <span class="mouse">Mouse</span>, terrified, piteously
  entreated him to spare its life. "Please let me go," it cried, "and one day I will repay you for your <span class="kindness">kindness</span>." The idea of so insignificant a creature ever being able to do anything for him amused the <span class="lion">Lion</span>  so much that he <span class="laugh">laughed</span> aloud, and good-humouredly let it go. But the <span class="mouse">Mouse</span>'s chance came, after all. One day the <span class="lion">Lion</span> got entangled in a net which had been spread for game
  by some hunters, and the <span class="mouse">Mouse</span> heard and recognised his roars of <span class="anger">anger</span> and ran to the spot. Without more ado it set to work to gnaw the ropes with its teeth, and succeeded before long in setting
  the <span class="lion">Lion</span> free. "There!" said the <span class="mouse">Mouse</span>, "you <span class="laugh">laughed</span> at me when I promised I would repay you: but now you see, even a <span class="mouse">Mouse</span> can help a <span class="lion">Lion</span>."
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>*Written by Aesop
</p>
```